# React - State not being set on initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code in my Product component to assign props received to a state
this state is not assigned when I create a new Product and render it on the parent by changing the state of Products list and hence re-loading products and even for existing objects, the colours and sizing don't appear unless you first load the page then refresh it.

The implementation is as follows:

1) They are defined in the state of the product class

```
 this.state = {
  colorsPicked: [],
  newProductSizes: []
};
```

2) They are passed in the component's *parent* class as props as follows:

```
           <Product
            colors={product.colors}
            sizes={product.sizes}
            updateProducts={this.updateProducts}
          />
```

3) They are supposedly set in the product class as follows:

```
async componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
 this.setState({
  colorsPicked: props.colors,
  newProductSizes: props.sizes
});
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the code of how you try to use this state (since you said they don't appear)?

Comment: Can I ask why your componentWillReceiveProps is async ?

Comment: {this.state.colorsPicked.map(color => (
                <Circle bgColor={color} />
              ))}

              <ButtonGroup size="lg" aria-label="First group">
                {this.state.newProductSizes.map(size => (
                  <Button variant="secondary">{size}</Button>
                ))}
              </ButtonGroup>

Comment: @dorriz idk i just copied it from somewhere it was async, removing async doesnt fix anything tho

Comment: As of React doc `componentWillReceiveProps` is considered unsafe (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) and it is sugessted to avoid it.

I'll sugest to init state in constructor. Props are already in place during construction.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is unsafe in React doc, you can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) or `componentDidUpdate` (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: What's your React version? Instead of copying random answers you should try to use `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: I tried all the methods you guys suggested, didnt work, just setting in constructor directly worked tho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting them via your constructor:

```
class Item extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            colorsPicked: props.colors,
            newProductSizes: props.sizes
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your best answer should be in here:

[React: You probably don't need derived state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)

If you absolutely must, you can try something with:

[static getDerivedStateFromProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)
This method will run before every render, including the first one.